# Apply sed replacement expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex, sed

I'm looking for a way to take `sed` replacement expressions, such as `s/hello/world/` (meaning replace all instances of 'hello' with 'world'), and apply them to a Java String.  Ideally I would like to have support for other `sed` features like capture groups and so on, but they're not strictly necessary.

Are there any good libraries for this kind of thing in Java?

---

I could try to parse the sed expression myself, but I'd rather not get into the rats nest of escape handling.

Comment: the solution provided works for you? If so please accept it, or try to better explain in what way is defective. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

In Java what you need is accomplished with `replaceAll()` method, provided as built in in the String class:

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,String replacement)
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Example:

```
String test1 = "hello world";
System.out.println(test1.replaceAll("hello","hi"));
//Output: "hi world"
```

Capturing groups in `replaceAll`:

```
String test2 = "invert:me";
System.out.println(test2.replaceAll("(.*):(.*)","$2:$1"))
//Output: "me:invert"
```

**NB**

- `replaceAll()` works as a `sed` substitution operation with global `/g` modifier.
- `replaceFirst()` works exactly as the method above **without** the global modifier (replace only the first occurrence)
- `replace()` is **different**. It does **not** accept any regex only literal string!

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted already

Comment: The Kotlin `replace(Regex, String)` has behavior similar to the Java `replaceAll(String, String)`.

Comment: To answer the question, this would need to explain how to parse a sed expression such as "s/hello/world/" to extract the correct "regex" and "replacement" parameters to pass to String's replaceAll.

Comment: @Tordanik I think you are right, the unix4j answer is closer to the OP's initial request. Anyway, there is value in this answer for those looking for a pure Java replacement too.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you are looking for this library:

[unix4j](https://github.com/tools4j/unix4j)

It is not actively developed since 2013, but otherwise it fits your needs. It allows you to write this:

```
cat test.txt | grep "Tuesday" | sed "s/kilogram/kg/g" | sort
```

into this:

```
Unix4j.cat("test.txt").grep("Tuesday").sed("s/kilogram/kg/g").sort();
```